# BroadcastReceiver with acton SCREEN_ON in background

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-widget

I want to listen when screen of device is on and update widget but `BroadcastReceiver` does not work when I close my app. It works only when application is running.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".WidgetProvider"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
    </receiver>
```

**The code is in `onCreate()`:**

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new WidgetProvider();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 8, the background processes have been restricted due to safety and battery consumption. Some Broadcast Receivers like:-

1. SCREEN_OFF
2. TIME_TICK
3. etc..

have been blocked.But, some of them like this:

1. REBOOT

work fine. This is to save the battery consumptions. This also prevents our app from opening activities when they are not necessary too.

Comment: But how can I do it? I need to update my widget often than 30 minutes!

Comment: You have to ask permission to ignore battery performance for the app. Then it will work

Comment: And what about another question for that?

Comment: I just want to update my widget every one minute or when `SCREEN_ON`. And I try to allow permission to ignore battery performance but it does not work. `OnReceive` do not work

Comment: Then u can use `Job Scheduler`